# How to write an exclusive query in SQL between tables?

Tags: sql, where-clause, where-in

Currently stuck on question that requires me to query data on count of user id's between 10 and 50 exclude 20 and 30.
Exact Question: Write a query that returns the count of all user_id records between 10 and 50, exclusive of the user IDs 20 and 30.

Tables to pull from down below...
created_at (date)
name (string)
address (string)
state (string)
zipcode (integer)
user_id (integer)

Answer (score 1):

Use `between` and `not in`:

```
select count(*) from mytable
where user_id between 10 and 50
and user_id not in (20, 30)
```

Comment: Great solution I edited your response and the solution I found that worked happened to be:                               SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
AND user_id NOT IN (20,30)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is modified from previous comment meant to be the answer. The answer is right based on the format and the basic syntax is correct from a clause-base perspective.
SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM purchases
WHERE user_id BETWEEN 10 AND 50
AND user_id NOT IN (20,30)